# change/retrieve CAS Server TGT cookie values after login

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, server, cas

I’m not very clear on how Single Log out works with CAS server 4.1 and hope for a clear and simple explanation to help resolve an issue i’m having with my client applications.

Currently SSO works fine with my two applications.

Users can login to application A,B and C, A and B are Ruby on Rails applications using ruby-cas client. C is a Java application using acegi security(Now Spring security)

When users logout of application A, they are redirected to CAS server logout view, but are still logged in to application B,C. Same goes for logging out of B,C.

Is SLO for Cas server 4.1 enabled by default?

Does SLO require any special configuration to work on CAS server?

Is there a way to get and store the cas TGT cookie (value of cas cookie)?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the ideal Solution but it seems to do the job. Using **CAS server 4.1**
Edit the ticketGrantingTicketCookieGenerator.xml file in the spring-configuration. 
Deploy CAS server as ROOT application, to avoid editing InitialFlowSetupAction.java class.
Changing the path of the cas ticket granting ticket with wildcard domain is not recommended for security reasons. In this particular cas to achieve single logout required it.
First create a filter in your application to save cas ticket granting cookie value to your session and on each request checks that the cookie valued saved in your session matches the cookie value from the request, if not invalidate the session and user will be redirected to CAS login, else it's business as usual.

```
  <bean id="ticketGrantingTicketCookieGenerator" class="org.jasig.cas.web.support.CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator"
                  c:casCookieValueManager-ref="cookieValueManager"
                  p:cookieSecure="true"
                  p:cookieMaxAge="-1"
                  p:cookieName="TGC"
                  p:cookieDomain=".example.org"
                  p:cookiePath="/"/>
```